# What kind of cable is this? (herman miller standing desk motor to power supply)

Tags: electrical, cables

One of the cords from the desk motor to power supply was snapped in half by the movers and I need to replace it on one side.

I still half of the cord with the connector pictured on the right side but the whitish connector on the left was accidentally cut and lost. If I could identify the whitish connector on the left perhaps I could reattach them somehow.

It's directly attached to a motor that powers an electric standing desk.

[image]

Comment: It is a custom-made electrical cable with electrical connectors that I've seen in cars and things, but aren't easily identifiable.

Can you splice the individual wires back together with a crimping tool, or by soldering them?  Might be easier than trying to find a replacement for the cable.

Comment: Those are called MOLEX connectors but the two pieces you are showing are not compatible.  One has 8 pins and the other has 6.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whiteish connector on the left was cut off and lost so I no longer have it. If I could identify that piece then perhaps I could do what you suggested!

Comment: @sara unfortunately, since the other end of the cable was lost, there is no way to know how the cable was wired, especially since the two ends have different numbers of pins. You really need to go to the manufacturer to get a replacement. Since the moving company destroyed the old one, you should have them pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it is an 8 pin Molex connector.  These are used in a lot of different products.  One common use is PCI-E extension cables.

One such example is here
[https://www.amazon.com/JacobsParts-8-Inch-Express-Power-Extension/dp/B01D0CVD0A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D0CVD0A)

However, nobody can answer this question fully without seeing what the other end plugs in to -- it isn't clear if there are two different cables, or if one cable splits into two branches.

In any event, looking at 8-pin Molex connectors will probably allow you to find something that will solve your problem.